# perf mem error event 'cpu/mem-stores/P' not supported

Tags: x86, profiling, perf

When I run

```
[bin]$ perf mem record
I get
failed: event 'cpu/mem-stores/P' not supported

bin]$ uname -a
Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 19:03:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bin]$ perf --version
perf version 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64.debug
```

Is there a means I can find why I am getting this error? Is it limited by the version of perf or is it limited only to sudo users (I am not) or my hardware does not support those events?

JFYI
On the machine if I run below command

```
[bin]$ perf mem record -e list
ldlat-loads  : available
ldlat-stores
```

Comment: What CPU micorarchitecture are you using?

Comment: @HadiBrais its an intel xeon server machine https://ark.intel.com/products/53677/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-8830-24M-Cache-2_13-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI

Comment: @MichaelPetch No, I meant the microarchitecture (Haswell, Skylake, etc.), not the ISA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Profiling store memory accesses (Precise Store) is available on Sandy Bridge and later. So it's not supported on your CPU. However, load profiling is supported as the output of the tool indicates.

By default, both loads and stores are profiled. But because Precise Store is not supported on your CPU, the tool emits an error. So you can profile loads only by passing the `-t load` switch.

Comment: Thanks its sad actually I want to run perf c2c to check false sharing stats on this machine, And I see perf c2c also failing with same error. So that means perf c2c cannot be executed on that machine. Sad news for me! Thanks for help.